# Test to identify active source in electrical network

Tags: batteries, network, port

I have a black box of a N-port electrical network and I wanted to know whether inside this box is there any active source of energy (i.e battery) present or not, so is it possible to determine active sources without opening the box? And how to do it (what test are required at ports ) ?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question so you need to show some effort at a solution or the question will be closed.

Comment: No, I was studying thevenin's theorem and this question comes to my mind

Answer (score 0):

Make the following considerations:

1.If the network does not contain internal sources and is not externally powered (voltage and/or current sources), what do you observe on the ports?

2. What changes if the network contains internal sources?

Answer (score 0):

For the general hypothetical case you describe, where the \$N\$ ports could be **any subset** of the internal circuit nodes and you can only observe the voltage and current between the ports, then there is no definitive way to tell if the internal circuit contains a source of power or not.

Comment: Trivial example: port 1 and 2 are connected together (directly). Inside the box is also a battery, resistor, and LED.